# PostgreSQL exclude extra comma from being used as a delimiter while parsing csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to copy data from a csv file into my database table. But the problem is that a column named `title` has some values that contain a comma within.

How can I exclude it from being used as a delimiter while parsing?

Sample data:

```
"Hold On, I'm Coming", The Canettes Blues Band, On Tap & In the Can, 34, 100, 282
```

I don't want the comma after "Hold on" to be used as a delimiter.

Comment: See this Stack DBA question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76812/escaping-delimiter-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or psql's `\copy` then use the options

```
format csv quote '"'
```

this will make the import ignore commas inside quoted values (which is what your sample data uses)

e.g. in `psql`

```
\copy target_table from the_input_file.txt with (format csv quote '"')
```